# angular 6 Multi-Page App How to

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing a complex information system, and our front-end stack is defined to use Angular Framework. I'm aware that Angular was planned and mostly suitable for Single-Page Applications. But at this stage, I'm facing an issue with MPA support from angular 6. Basically, our client's requirement is that to view certain element in a system, it has to be opened in a different tab because normally people will open multiple and use it to gather or compare elements between each other.

My current app is distributed among multiple lazy loaded modules, so my question is what is the best way to implement MPA support for angular, in order to solve this issue? I know that if I open a link in a separate tab, the whole application has to be downloaded by the client and only then he can view the particular page. Can anybody advice on maybe certain solutions for this case, or whether its possible to not download the whole app on a new tab? Thanks.

PS. I've browsed through the whole internet, but haven't found any solution for this.

Comment: How about make use of `service workers`? They can cache `js` files

Comment: how about instead of using angular routing module, use location.href for routing.

Comment: @PatrykBrejdak Any practical example of how to use that service workers? In any way if a new tab is opened the whole app will be loaded again isnt it, or I dont understand something ?

Comment: @simplelenz what does it change ? I'm already not using a router for navigation but opening a tab, the app will still be loaded again

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a multipage app using angular these days. There we use normal location.href navigation for routing rather than using the angular router module. This way angular app can be used as a multipage app. When we do this, every time when we are reloading the browser, angular bootstrap everything and loads from app component onwards. So when you use lazy loading, you can limit the the no.of modules loading every time the browser refreshed. same happens when you open something in a new tab.

As suggested by @Suresh Kumar Ariya, server side rendering is to just render the static content of a page while the javascript files needed for the dynamic functionality of that page loads in the background. So I don't think this is what you are looking for unless you wanna just serve static content fast for user experience improvement.

What you can do is try to do more lazy loading to minimize the initial loading and optimize your code

Comment: Thanks for reply, actually I wasn’t familiar with service workers, after small research I think this would be applicable in my case, because after AOT compilation the new tab is loading within 2 seconds so I think if vendors and other scripts will be cached the new tab should load very fast

Comment: yes all you can do is to use optimization techniques to render faster. you can also use --build-optimizer flag when building

Comment: Alright thanks  anyway after I implement this I’ll update the answer here on what was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also opt for Angular with Service Side Rendering Concept. So Data can be shared b/w client and server end. https://angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: Hi Suresh, have you tried to accomplish this previously? will it help in my particular case ?

Comment: I haven't worked on any SSR with Angular. You can try creating a Sample project with one use case.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but haven't touched it yet. Also is it correct to say that the whole framework is purposely designed for SPA only ? angularjs was able to handle this easily if I'm not wrong

Comment: Angular framework is built with Modern Web API, has better performance compared to Angularjs1.x. Has Service Workers Support. And finally its a platform which can be used for creating Web Apps that will work on Mobile, Desktop and Universal.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for advices, solved the issue with `service workers`, now all tabs are loading instantly =) thanks to @Patryk Brejdak

Comment: Great to hear that :), however it would be great if you describe solution a little more, so this answer will be more valueable for others who struggling with similar problem and also accept this answer if it's solved your problem.

Comment: Actually, I haven't done much just simply installed the service workers, with default settings ))) and a new tab is opening is using cached version of the website, which is exactly same as if I open page using angular router. Pretty much that's it. Another good thing to optimize is use server side rendering as was suggested earlier on, for a page startup.